# Passing event objects from trigger function to another function

Tags: events, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I decided to break this `onEdit(e)` trigger function up into multiple functions, but when I did, the event objects `(e)` portion got "lost."  After messing with it for a while, I finally got it to work again, but I don't think it's the most efficient solution.

Any suggestions, or is this good enough? Basically, I just added `var e = e;` and that made it work again.

```js
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(e);
  
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Estimate'){   
    var e = e;
    Logger.log("Starting subCatDV...");
    subCatDV(e);
    Logger.log("Finished subCatDV!");

    
    Logger.log("Starting itemDV...");
    itemDV(e);
    Logger.log("Finished itemDV!");


    Logger.log("Starting subItemDV...");
    subItemDV(e);
    Logger.log("Finished subItemDV!");
    
  }    
  
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Items'){
    subCatDV();
  }
  
  return;
    
}
```

Here is the function that didn't seem to be receiving the `event objects`

```js
function subItemDV(e){
  // Populate sub-item data validations
  
  var estss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Estimate');
  var itemss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Items');
  var subItemDVss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('subItemDataValidations');
  var activeCell = estss.getActiveCell();
  
  Logger.log("I'm in subItemDV...");
  Logger.log(e);
  Logger.log(activeCell);
  
  Logger.log("Checking sheet name...");
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Items') return;
    
    Logger.log("Not in 'Items' sheet!  Moving on...");
    
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
    var subItem = subItemDVss.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),activeCell.getColumn(),itemss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var subItemIndex = subItem[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;
    
    
    Logger.log("Checking subItemIndex...");
    
    if(subItemIndex != 0){
      
      var subItemValidationRange = subItemDVss.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),4,1,subItemDVss.getLastColumn());
      var subItemValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(subItemValidationRange).build();
      
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(subItemValidationRule);

      Logger.log("Finished checking subItemIndex...");
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, clarify during what call and under what circumstances the `event object` gets lost? It is constructed [only in response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to triggers (in your case - "onEdit") and is persisted throughout the callback chain if you do not reassign or modify it. Btw, since your two `if` statements check the same thing, you should use one `if..else` statement instead

Comment: Hello @OlegValter! Thank you for your response!  I edited the OP to reflect the affected function.

Comment: Hi Trey! Thanks for clarifying! Could you please tell what was the issue you experienced? Judging from your current code, there is nothing that can cause the `event object` to become `undefined` (btw, is this what you mean by "lost"?)

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is what I meant.  I'm just fumbling through GAS, trying to teach myself.  So I don't always use appropriate lingo.  Before I added `var e = e;` and added `(e)` to each function, it just wasn't passing the values and stopping mid-function.  Hence all of the `Logger` sprinkled throughout.  Trying to pinpoint where it was stopping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as not to inflate discussion in comments: you can *safely remove* the `var e = e` assignment from the script, as it does not affect the problems that your updated version of the script solved:

1. `e` is an *event object* that is constructed as a response to trigger being fired. Since in your case the trigger is an `onEdit(e)` trigger, event object is `undefined` until an edit is made in the target Spreadsheet (please, note that *script-triggered* edits do not count);
2. Even if you called the function with a parameter (like `doSomething(e)`), in case you either do not access the parameter via the `arguments` object, or explicitly define it in a function declaration `function doSomething(e)`, the event object won't be persisted;

Also, you might've missed the `e` binding in the last `subCatDV()` call + the `if` statement can be optimized (btw, don't use the [equality comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality), use the [identity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) comparison instead, it will save you debugging time in the future):

```
var name = e.range.getSheet().getName();
if(name === 'Estimate') {
  doSomething(e);
}else if(name === 'Items') { //identity comparison ensures type match;
  doSomethingElse(e);
}
```

**Useful links**

1. event object [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
2. `arguments` object [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments);

Comment: please do not use === against string literals

Comment: did you mean string objects, though? As `'foo'==='foo'` passes the strict equality test, as well as the `var f = 'foo'; f==='foo'` and `var f = 'foo'; var ff = 'foo'; f===ff` and even the template literals.